# Passing a parameter to a callable function

Tags: php

I can't seem to get this to work. I have a function which takes a parameter which I would like to call.

```
protected function testFunc($param) {
    echo $param;
}

protected function testCall(callable $testFunc) {
    call_user_func($testFunc);
}

public function testProg($param) {
    $this->testCall([$this, 'testFunc']);
}
```

I have tried

```
$this->testCall([[$this, 'testFunc'], $param]);
```

and

```
$this->testCall([$this, 'testFunc($param)']);
```

and

```
$this->testCall('TestClass::testFunc($param));
```

Are closures my only option here or how can I pass a parameter to a callable function

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To call a method (in your example `function`(s) are class methods), you have to use this syntax:

```
protected function testCall( $testFunc )
{
    call_user_func( array( $this, $testFunc ) );
}
```

To pass an argument, you have to use this syntax:

```
protected function testCall( $testFunc, $arg )
{
    call_user_func( array( $this, $testFunc ), $arg );
}

(...)

$this->testCall( 'testFunc', $arg );
```

To pass more than one arguments, you have to use `call_user_func_array`:

```
protected function testCall( $testFunc, array $args )
{
    call_user_func_array( array( $this, $testFunc ), $args );
}

(...)

$this->testCall( 'testFunc', array( $arg1, $arg2 ) );
```

#### Edit:

The above code works fine, but — as quick-wittedly noted in comments — this previous code:

```
protected function testCall( callable $testFunc, $arg )
```

doesn't work in above context.

To use it, the above methods and call must be modified in:

```
protected function testCall( callable $testFunc, $arg )
{
    call_user_func( $testFunc , $arg );
}

(...)

$this->testCall( array( $this, 'testFunc'), $arg );
```

Comment: Surely callable implies a callable, but your code implies it's a string (method name).

Comment: @Progrock Not sure that your point is exact: all the OP code is in the class context, and in this context is correct passing the method as string. `$this->testCall()` is different that `call_user_func( array($instance, 'funcname') )`. Please also note that methods are protected, so it is not possible call it outside the class.

Comment: Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to Caller::testCall() must be callable, string given.  Before you removed the hint.

Comment: @Progrock Edited answer. Thank you for your annotation

Answer (score 3):

Modify your code as follows

```
protected function testFunc($param) {
    echo $param;
}

protected function testCall(callable $testFunc, $param) {
    call_user_func($testFunc, $param);
}

public function testProg($param) {
    $this->testCall([$this, 'testFunc'], $param);
}
```

That way, first function (`testCall`) is accepting arguments for second function (`testFunc`).

This code works only if you're passing a single argument. If you wish to pass an array, use `call_user_func_array`

Answer (score 0):

If you know the number of arguments - pass'em to `call_user_func`:

```
call_user_func($func_name, $arg1, $arg2)
```

If you don't know the number of arguments - pass'em to `call_user_func_array`:

```
call_user_func_array($func_name, [$arg1, $arg2, $arg3]);
```

Answer (score 0):

In a static context the program would be:

```
class Foo {

    public static function testFunc($text) {
        echo "Hello" . $text;
    }

    public static function testCall(callable $function, $parameter) {
        call_user_func($function, $parameter);
    }

    public static function testProg($parameter) {
        self::testCall([self::class, 'testFunc'], $parameter);
    }

}

Foo::testProg(" World");
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35577050/5279996)